# How do I extract month two digits varchar from data? SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

This is my data set

[image: data]

I am making a stored procedure and the column is in varchar. I have tried to convert to datetime but wasn't successful to do it... I am trying to extract just the month in two digits eg. 01,02,03 to make a table like this.

[image: table]

```
CREATE Proc qe 
AS
BEGIN

SELECT LEFT(CREATED_TIME,4) AS 'YEAR' , COUNT(*) AS 'NO OF POSTS'
FROM Sheet1$ 
GROUP BY  LEFT(CREATED_TIME,4)

/**SELECT LEFT(CREATED_TIME,7 (RIGHT CREATED_TIME,19))  AS 'MONTH',        
COUNT(*) AS 'NO OF POSTS'
FROM Sheet1$ 
GROUP BY LEFT(CREATED_TIME,7 (RIGHT CREATED_TIME,19))**/

END 

EXEC qe
```

How do I extract month eg. 01, 02, 03 it staying in varchar? No converting? I really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: table name sounds like excel is involved. does the issue involves excel and/or an excel worksheet/workbook?

Comment: yes, it is imported from an excel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a string you could do this like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CREATED_TIME,6,2);
```

Just for completness: To get the month with two digits out of a date you can go like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(STR(MONTH(GETDATE()),2),' ','0');
```

Comment: I ended up converting it after using a sub-string for the column. Thanks all for answering!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [zero padding function in SQL Server](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-pad-leading-zeros.aspx)
Please check referenced SQL tutorial

```
select dbo.udfLeftSQLPadding( DATEPART(mm,GETDATE()),2,'0')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MONTH(CAST(create_time AS datetime))
```

Comment: OP said that converting to `datetime` fails.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select right('0'+cast(month_num as varchar(2)) ,2) as month, month_count
from
(
    select datepart(month, cast(replace(created_time, '+0000','') as datetime)) as month_num
    , COUNT(*) AS 'NO OF POSTS' as month_count
    FROM Sheet1$ 
    GROUP BY  datepart(month, cast(replace(created_time, '+0000','') as datetime))
) temp
```